# Disk Partition is disabled for newly format disk

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility, partition

I am using macOS High Sierra.

I erased my 1 TB disk using disk utility to using Mac OS Extended (Journaled) file system.

I want to perform partition on my disk and want to split into two parts, i.e. 500 GB both.

But I am unable to do it as partition symbol is disabled in disk utility.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Other than the "boot" portion in the linked dupe question/answer, everything else is the same.

Answer (score 2):

The command below assumes the external drive is still `disk3`, as shown in the OP's image.

```
diskutil  partitionDisk  disk3  2  GPT  JHFS+  Seagate1  500G  JHFS+  Seagate2  R
```

This command will erase the entire contents of the external drive.